# How can I change this symbol? Magento

Tags: magento

I have this page:

http://www.moment-of-style.com/onlajn-magazin/pal-to-pidzhaki/denim-bomber-148.html

I simply replace this with something and can not find where to do this modification.

I put an image to better understand what they want

[image]

I tried to follow this tutorial but I could not.

http://magentocoders.blogspot.in/2011/10/insert-rupee-symbol-instead-of-rs-in.html

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the shown currency is Russian Ruble. The currency code for Rubles is RUB, and the currency symbol is руб. The question isn't clear. So i will give you suggestions as i understood your question.

- First of all, if you want to use Russian Ruble as your currency then the symbol 'руб' is perfect. Although no symbol exists officially, руб (three Cyrillic characters which are the equivalent of RUB in Russian) is currently used.
- Second, if you want to use RUB instead of руб then follow the below steps. It works perfect for me.

  - Goto->AdminPanel->Configuration->Currency Setup->Base Currency(Set Russian Rubel). Do the same for Default Display Currency and allowed currency.
- Now Go to->Adminpanel->System->Manage Currency->Symbols-> Change your symbol here(You can see руб here, change it).
- Third and the last, characters of your site suggest the Serbian language(as per Google translate). You can do same as step 2 for the Serbian currency.

Let me know, if you need any help.